# Adding also "action" in "if" function - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this if statement to load a specific css for each controller:

```
<% if params[:controller] == "session" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "easybreeze", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "authentication" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I add a specific action of that controller in my statement?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested [in the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters), you could be using `controller_name` and `action_name` instead of `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]`.

So, your if statement will be something like:

```
<% if controller_name == "session" and action_name == "new" %>
```

Comment: Since there is absolutely no info *why* one should use `controller_name` and `action_name` instead of `params[:controller]` and `params[:actions]` in that piece of documentation, I changed your answer to *could* instead of *should*. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: TIL that the `controller_name` and `action_name` functions exist. I've always used `params`.

That documentation *does* say you "should" use controller_name and action_name, although it doesn't specify why. In my opinion they're a cleaner and clearer way of doing it than using `params`.

Comment: @GeorgeMillo I agree that those methods are probably better, but if the documentation says *should* it should also explain why. I am blaming the documentation here, not this answer.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with your edit, you're right that the documentation should explain itself. Was just giving my own opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
params[:controller] == 'something' && params[:action] == 'something'
```